# Printing a number in sequence using C - Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Sample pattern is given,

```
input :    16
output:    16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16
```

If the input is 10, then program should print output as

```
10 5 0 5 10
```

Note: The above sequences decrement/increment by 5.

The challenge is to not declare any variables or loops. use only recursion.

I have tried with the following code.

```
void sequence(int input, int base){

    input = input - (input > 0?5:-5); //main execution
    printf("input:%d\n",input);
    if(input == base)return;
    sequence(input,base);
}
```

//for eg. input and base(initial Value) is 16. The above method recurse itself until input = base.

I can print upto this sequence (in Bold)

**16 11 6 1 -4** 1 6 11 16

How to complete the sequence. In the above method, in main execution line, i need to check condition as `input = input - (input < 0?5:-5);` to print the remaining sequence. But i am not sure how can i do this without any variables or loops. Is there any algorithm available or any other better solution.

Comment: Is *left recursion* or *right recursion* required? If not, just do the output again after your test for stopping the recursion... and btw, you won't ever need the `base` argument ... reaching the top frame of your recursion is enough.

Comment: This is not possible with these constraints. You have to use variables, at least "arguments".

Comment: @Olaf, that's probably why it says not to *declare* variables. I'd add not to *mutate* any, too. Cleary, the objective is to do this the "functional" way. I hope showing the solution here doesn't spoil the learning experience...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Arguments are not declared? (btw. OP very likely confuses declaration and definition; I do not see a problem just declaring a variables, as you cannot use it anyway until you define it ...)

Comment: @Olaf a function declaration is not a variable declaration. And yes, declaring a variable that isn't defined anywhere wouldn't interfere with the *functional* nature of the code, but it would be just useless -- consider this really nitpicking here, sorry ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Where did I state this? But an argument is actually a local variable (with its type/position known outside), too (languages which allow to use their names in the caller make this more visible). And it also has a declaration/definition. I did not talk about the function itself.

Comment: @Olaf, not it doesn't. It's part of the function declaration/definition. And being a variable in [tag:c] is a technical detail here, completely irrelevant to the question that's obviously about learning / teaching functional programming. Just be so kind and stop commenting *ultra-wise* stuff that just distracts from the topic, thank you.

Comment: Well, the whole body of a function is part of the function definition, so the same applies to local variables? (I never intended to take this that deep; - actually you did)

Comment: I was so unhappy with the asymmetry of the solutions given so far, that I [added a section about it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32677877/2932052). Thanks for having a look at it :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some example code to my comment, which would match if it doesn't have to be strictly left- or right-recursive:

```
void sequence(int n)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    if (n > 0)
    {
        sequence(n-5);
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
}
```

Further notes:

1.) This seems to be about *functional programming*, where a key concept is that you can never *assign* a variable ... see how it is avoided here. (Strictly speaking, it's not functional because of the `printf` side effects)

2.) It's not strictly left- or right-recursive (meaning the recursion happens *in the middle* of evaluation), so it can't be easily transformed to something iterative.

Comment: Great: is short and works! I made a [life demo](http://ideone.com/Jok0hC) for it.

Comment: What could be the output for sequence(-16) ?

Comment: @kkk just `-16`. It's not specified in the OP description whether this should output anything or not, here it will ...

Comment: @kkk what would be *your favourite output* for -16?

Comment: something like this -16 -11 -6 -1 4 -1 -6 -11 -16

Comment: @kkk only from the given examples in the OP, this is a possible, but IMHO strange assumption.

Comment: @kkk: That would have reverse directions (increment, then decrement) compared to the original. I'd expect it to print `-16 -16`. The second `printf` should be outside the `if`, but that would print the inner twice, so this might have to be handled specially.

Comment: @Olaf, no it shouldn't, see the examples, the lowest number is always only printed once

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I edited the comment. Fair enough, as it is not exactly specified. It is always difficult and often impossible to treat border-conditions correctly from few samples and without an exact description.

Comment: @Olaf yes, so you could even see kkk's example as the "expected" output if the rule you derive from the examples would be to approach `0` in steps of `5`. I just think what I decided for is most "natural" ...

Comment: No, I disagree with @kkk. The sequence always first decrements until it is `< 0`, then increments. Start is always printed twice, end once. Problem is that a negative value is both.

Comment: @Olaf, there's just no example for a negative start, so you could assume anything that somehow follows a consistent rule for all cases and are left with multiple choices. I choose what I found most natural (and, of course, the one giving the simplest recursive code)

Comment: See my previous comment!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the recursion should stop when it reaches `0` or below. So try this condition in you recursive function (reduced to only one argument):

```
void sequence(input) {
    // print input
    if (input > 0) {
        // recursive call
        sequence(input);
    }
    // print input again (sometimes...)
}
```

### Update: Let's talks about Symmetry

For the sake of symmetry, also the [reverse version](https://ideone.com/nYpP06) of [Felix's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32677904/2932052) can be used

```
void sequence(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d ", n);
        sequence(n-5);
    }
    printf("%d ", n);
}
```

Both feature a kind of asymmetry that seems not to fit to the palindromic structure of the problem, and there is another problem: the blemish of a trailing space. So let's introduce to you a [obvious solution](https://ideone.com/0vfUZM) that deals with these tiny(?) flaws:

```
void sequence(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d ", n); sequence(n-5); printf(" %d", n);
    } else {
        printf("%d", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: base is nothing but the initial value. That it 16.

Comment: This will print the middle (minimum) value twice; the second print statement should go inside the `if` body.

Comment: @MOehm Yes, I know, that's why I added the "(sometimes...)" in the second comment ;-)

Comment: @Wolf the last one is nice if whitespace matters. Of course it's still not L or R-recursive ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use two different functions to cout up and down:

```
void down(int input, int base) {
    printf("input:%d\n",input);
    if(input > 0) down(input - 5, base);
    else up(input + 5, base);
}

void up(int input, int base) {
    printf("input:%d\n",input);
    if(input == base) return;
    up(input + 5, base);
}
```

Start the calculation by calling `down`.

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/499dc30bd5d4e924)</kbd>

Comment: Hmm, you are already going up again when you return from the recursive function that goes down.

Comment: No, see the live demo.

Comment: Yes, of course. You recurse twice as deep as you need to. Maybe my comment was ambiguous; it did not refer to your solution, which works but is needlessly long, but to the supposed solution, which is to have another print stapement after recursing.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But this answer shows that a variable can be replaced by calling another recursive path, which can be useful sometimes. (That's why I think this answer adds value.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printSequence(int input) {
    printf("%d ", input);
    if (input <= 0)
        return;
    printSequence(input - 5);
    printf("%d ", input);
}

int main ()
{
    int input = 0;
    scanf("%d", &input);

    printSequence(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `base case` of your recursive code seems wrong. I think your code goes into infinite recursion the way it is. You can use a flag to achieve your sequence:

```
void sequence(int input, int base){
    static int flag = 0;
    //input = input - (input > 0?5:-5); //main execution, wrong
    printf("input:%d\n",input);
    input -= (flag == 0)?5:-5;          //use flag for base case of sequence
    if(input <= 0)
        flag = 1;
    if(input == base){
        printf("input:%d\n",input);
        return;
    }
    sequence(input,base);
}
```

Comment: Variable should not be used (mentioned in the question) and also it's not a good practice to use flags :)

Comment: ah..yes. I used a flag which is wrong acc to OP's conditions, but why do you say it is bad practice to use flags?

Comment: i meant w.r.t above OP